# Is there a better way to bind to JObject with XAML on Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am pulling JSON from a Node API.  I want to be able to just parse the response with a JObject instead of a pre-defined type.  This would give me more flexibility as to what I want to do.

Here is a sample of what the data might look like.

```
{
  section: {
    title: "Login",
    body: "This is your body!"
  }
}
```

Here is a sample of what the XAML I have tried.  This does not show anything.  The label is blank with the binding, but it doesn't throw an error.
Example 1:

```
<Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
       Text="{Binding Path=[section][body]}"
       x:Name="Body">
</Label>
```

Here is a working binding with the same data.  While this technically works, I am expecting more than a couple levels deep of objects.  I could potentially just set the BindingContext for parent controls, but that seems like it would get messy.
Example 2:

```
<Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
       BindingContext="{Binding Path=[section]}"
       Text="{Binding Path=[body]}"
       x:Name="Body">
</Label>
```

Comment: If you have a complicated json string, you'd better define a model class for display. This general binding conversation is adapted for simple structure.

Comment: In this project, we are trying to create a dynamic screen.  I was hoping to pass XAML to the application and render that on the screen without having to push an update through the app store.  The only part I haven't figured out is how to bind to a JObject.  The app will have certain screens that work like a basic CMS.  The administrator would be able to change content on the these certain screens.

Comment: Hi, did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

At last, I find we have to add a simple dot between each property to make it work.

i.e. The string is:

```
string jsonStr = @"{
                        section: 
                        { 
                        title: 
                        {
                            subtitle: ""subtitle""
                        },
                        body: ""This is your body!""
                        },

                    }";
var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonStr);
BindingContext = jsonObject;
```

And the xaml binding code is:

```
<Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=[section].[title].[subtitle]}" />
```

The label displays the correct string "subtitle".